# Creating polygon with esrieditor.editor in C#?

Tags: arcobjects, c#

How can I make a polygon using esrieditor.editor in ArcObjects?

I tried this method:

```
workspaceEdit.StartEditOperation();
IFeature feature = featureClass.CreateFeature();
Polygon p2 = featureClass.GetFeature(0).Shape as Polygon;

feature.Shape = p2 as IPolygon;

ISubtypes subtypes = (ISubtypes)featureClass;
IRowSubtypes rowSubtypes = (IRowSubtypes)feature;

rowSubtypes.InitDefaultValues();
feature.Store();
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code, do you get any error messages?

Comment: i am using this code  UID editorExtension = new UIDClass();
            editorExtension.Value = "esriEditor.Editor";
            IEditor editor = ArcMap.Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(editorExtension) as IEditor;
            editor.StartEditing(workspace);      .   i want  after start editing automatically start polygon drawing

Answer (score 3):

To create a polygon you need a collection of vertices (points) as [IPointCollection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000275000000) as a [Ring Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m00000466000000) then assemble as an [IGeometryCollection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m000001v1000000) as a [Polygon Class](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002m0000045r000000). Polygons are made from rings, at least one exterior and potentially several interior rings (holes) which is why they're a geometry collection. Polylines (lines) are made from paths in the same way multipoints are made from points.

```
object gMissing = System.Type.Missing;
IPoint pNewPoint;
IGeometryCollection pOutGeomColl = new PolygonClass();
IPointCollection pOutPntColl = new RingClass();
for (i = 0;i<SomeCounter;i++)
{
  pNewPoint = new PointClass();
  pNewPoint.PutCoords(X[i], Y[i]); // assuming you have an array of X and Y values
  pOutPntColl.AddPoint(pNewPoint, gMissing, gMissing);
}
pNewPoint = new PointClass();
pNewPoint.PutCoords(X[0], Y[0]); // first point must be the same as last point
pOutPntColl.AddPoint(pNewPoint, gMissing, gMissing);

pOutGeomColl.AddGeometry((IGeometry)pOutPntColl, gMissing, gMissing);
IGeometry pOutGeom = (IGeometry)pOutGeomColl;
pOutGeom.SpatialReference = pSR; // cast geometry collection to a geometry
feature.Shape = pOutGeom;
```

Potentially you could loop to add several rings but this should get you started. BTW try to avoid using [IFeature.shape](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//002500000330000000) to 'get' a geometry, this can have unexpected results if you change the geometry in memory, use [IFeature.ShapeCopy](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/ShapeCopy_Property/002500000331000000/) to get a copy of the shape that is no longer linked to the feature. Only use the Shape to *set* the geometry prior to an [IFeature.Store()](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007wv000000) or [Insert/update cursor update/insert](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000002vs000000).